# Nav Footer(poor alignment) Overlapping with content?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

new to code and Bootstrap using online tutorials. I have made my first page, but I cannot get the Nav Footer to align correctly. I want email and phone number to stack in a column aligned LEFT in sm xs. And FB button to keep RIGHT.

I've tried different methods on CSS and now the NAV Footers top is Overlapping with the content bottom. I'm not sure if I've messed up CSS for the Nav Footer or Listbox padding.
Very Frustrated, any ideas?

[image: xs Image fully scrolled down]

[Codeply code](https://www.codeply.com/go/b7i2U9BsZU)

```css
/* Prog Blue #1d91d3 */
/* Prog Grey #717c89 */
/* Prog Yellow #f5c014 */

/* nav background off-white */
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

/* nav Brand Text Color */
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #141414;
}

/* Nav Brand Text Hover */
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #717c89;
}

/* remove Nav Carousel Gap */
.navbar {
  margin:0; /*add this*/
}

.navbar-static-top { 
  z-index: auto; 
  border-width: 0px; /* boarder around navbar */
} 

/* nav link text color black */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #141414;
}

/* nav link text-hover */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #717c89;
}

/* active link */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #FFF5E6;
  background-color: #141414;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #555;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

/* caret */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret {
  border-top-color: #777;
  border-bottom-color: #777;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:focus .caret {
  border-top-color: #333;
  border-bottom-color: #333;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a .caret, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover .caret, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus .caret {
  border-top-color: #555;
  border-bottom-color: #555;
}
/* mobile version */
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #DDD;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #DDD;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #777;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #333;
  }
}

/* Carousel */

.carousel img {
  min-width: 100%; /* full screen width */
  margin-bottom: 20px; /* carousel body gap */
}

/*!
* Better Bootstrap Carousel V1.0.0
*
* Handcrafted by @haydennedyah from #LetsFixTheWeb
*
* Url http://LetsFixTheWeb.com
*/
.carousel-control {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 0px;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.carousel-control.right {
  right: 0px;
  opacity: 0; /* Transparent Area Right */
}

.carousel-control.left {
  opacity: o; /* Transparent Area Left */
}

.carousel-control:hover{
  opacity: 0;
}

/* text box */
.carousel-caption {
  right: 0;
  left: 1em;
  padding: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: left;
}
/* remove carousel indicators */
.carousel-indicators {
  display: none;
}

.row {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

/* main body */

/* (p) */
p {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

/* navber fixed bottom*/

.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  background-color: #141414;
  display: inline;
}

nav li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: inline;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline;
}

nav a {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #717c89;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fblink {
  float: right;
}

.fblink a {
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding: 8px 18px;
}

.fblink a:active {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Progression</a>
      <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Physio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Massage</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Beauty</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">First Aid</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>

</nav>

<!-- Carousel -->


<!-- opening div -->  
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"> 

    <!-- open listbox -->
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-aCIY16PFylg/VsW6L-YwpqI/AAAAAAAAADA/wSTG1QlJLqY/w1310-h524-no/Progression_Val_dIsere.png" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>Physio Massage Beauty First-Aid</h4>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-WHXl1TAoHoQ/VsW7_mHWeQI/AAAAAAAAAEQ/nzQm8w62c3s/w1310-h524-no/Progression_Massage_Budha.png" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>A wide range of Massage Therapies</h4>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-lj7DIStRI8M/VthrRPFcQFI/AAAAAAAAAFY/2ynRLjTZTnI/w1310-h524-no/Progression_Beauty_Therapies.png" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>Nails - Facials - Waxing</h4>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div> <!--close listbox -->

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <!-- Glyphicon Cheveron Left removed -->
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <!-- Cheveron Right removed -->
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>

</div>

<!-- Home Content Container-->

<!-- container opener -->  
<div class ="container">

  <!-- open row -->
  <div class ="row">

    <!-- colums -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/physiotherapy-concept-360x165.jpg" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Physiotherapy</h3>
          <p>...</p>
        </div><!-- close caption --> 
      </div><!-- close thumbnail -->
    </div><!-- close colum -->

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/massage360x165.jpg" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Massage</h3>
          <p>...</p>
        </div><!-- close caption --> 
      </div><!-- close thumbnail -->
    </div><!-- close colum -->

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/Facial2-360x165.jpg" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Beauty</h3>
          <p>...</p>
        </div><!-- close caption --> 
      </div><!-- close thumbnail -->
    </div><!-- close colum -->

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/First-aid-360x165.jpg" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>First aid</h3>
          <p>...</p>
        </div><!-- close caption --> 
      </div><!-- close thumbnail -->
    </div><!-- close colum -->

  </div><!-- close row -->

</div><!-- close container -->


<!-- nav footer -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">

  <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone pull-left"><p class="navbar-text"> +33 62738 5646</p></a> <!-- nav foot left items -->

  <div class="fblink">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ProgressionPhysiotherapyMassageFirstAid/" class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x pull-right"></a> <!-- nav foot right items FB #x2 -->
  </div> 

</div><!-- close nav fix bottom -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">+33 62738 5646</a></li>
    <li text-align="right"><a href="#">massage@progressionski.com</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="fblink"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/ProgressionPhysiotherapyMassageFirstAid/" target="_blank" class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x pull-right"></a> <!-- nav foot right items FB #x2 -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't set `margin-bottom` on Bootstrap's `row` class, instead add a class to the parent "Home Content Container" (`container-home` in this case) and increase the `margin-bottom` value on `xs` screens (max width 479px).

```css
/* Prog Blue #1d91d3 */
/* Prog Grey #717c89 */
/* Prog Yellow #f5c014 */

/* nav background off-white */
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

/* nav Brand Text Color */
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #141414;
}

/* Nav Brand Text Hover */
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #717c89;
}

/* remove Nav Carousel Gap */
.navbar {
  margin: 0; /*add this*/
}

.navbar-static-top { 
  z-index: auto; 
  border-width: 0; /* boarder around navbar */
} 

/* nav link text color black */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #141414;
}

/* nav link text-hover */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #717c89;
}

/* active link */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #FFF5E6;
  background-color: #141414;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #555;
  background-color: #ff0;
}

/* caret */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret {
  border-top-color: #777;
  border-bottom-color: #777;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:focus .caret {
  border-top-color: #333;
  border-bottom-color: #333;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a .caret, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover .caret, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus .caret {
  border-top-color: #555;
  border-bottom-color: #555;
}
/* mobile version */
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ddd;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #777;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #333;
  }
}

/* Carousel */

.carousel img {
  min-width: 100%; /* full screen width */
  margin-bottom: 20px; /* carousel body gap */
}

/*!
* Better Bootstrap Carousel V1.0.0
*
* Handcrafted by @haydennedyah from #LetsFixTheWeb
*
* Url http://LetsFixTheWeb.com
*/
.carousel-control {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.carousel-control.right {
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0; /* Transparent Area Right */
}

.carousel-control.left {
  opacity: 0; /* Transparent Area Left */
}

.carousel-control:hover{
  opacity: 0;
}

/* text box */
.carousel-caption {
  right: 0;
  left: 1em;
  padding: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  text-align: left;
}
/* remove carousel indicators */
.carousel-indicators {
  display: none;
}


/* main body */

/* (p) */
p {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

/* navber fixed bottom*/

.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  background-color: #141414;
  display: inline;
}

nav li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: inline;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline;
}

nav a {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #717c89;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container-home {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}
@media (max-width: 479px) {
  .container-home {
    margin-bottom: 120px;
  }
}

.fblink {
  float: right;
}

.fblink a {
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding: 8px 18px;
}

.fblink a:active {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Progression</a>
      <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Physio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Massage</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Beauty</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">First Aid</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>

</nav>

<!-- Carousel -->


<!-- opening div -->    
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"> 

    <!-- open listbox -->
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-aCIY16PFylg/VsW6L-YwpqI/AAAAAAAAADA/wSTG1QlJLqY/w1310-h524-no/Progression_Val_dIsere.png" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>Physio Massage Beauty First-Aid</h4>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-WHXl1TAoHoQ/VsW7_mHWeQI/AAAAAAAAAEQ/nzQm8w62c3s/w1310-h524-no/Progression_Massage_Budha.png" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>A wide range of Massage Therapies</h4>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-lj7DIStRI8M/VthrRPFcQFI/AAAAAAAAAFY/2ynRLjTZTnI/w1310-h524-no/Progression_Beauty_Therapies.png" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>Nails - Facials - Waxing</h4>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div> <!--close listbox -->

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <!-- Glyphicon Cheveron Left removed -->
    <span class="glyphicon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <!-- Cheveron Right removed -->
    <span class="glyphicon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>

</div>

<!-- Home Content Container-->

<!-- container opener -->   
<div class="container container-home">

  <!-- open row -->
  <div class="row">

    <!-- colums -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/physiotherapy-concept-360x165.jpg" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Physiotherapy</h3>
          <p>...</p>
        </div><!-- close caption -->  
      </div><!-- close thumbnail -->
    </div><!-- close colum -->

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/massage360x165.jpg" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Massage</h3>
          <p>...</p>
        </div><!-- close caption -->  
      </div><!-- close thumbnail -->
    </div><!-- close colum -->

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/Facial2-360x165.jpg" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Beauty</h3>
          <p>...</p>
        </div><!-- close caption -->  
      </div><!-- close thumbnail -->
    </div><!-- close colum -->

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/First-aid-360x165.jpg" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>First aid</h3>
          <p>...</p>
        </div><!-- close caption -->  
      </div><!-- close thumbnail -->
    </div><!-- close colum -->

  </div><!-- close row -->

</div><!-- close container -->


<!-- nav footer -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">

  <!-- nav foot left items -->
  <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone pull-left">
    <p class="navbar-text"> +33 62738 5646</p>
  </a>

  <div class="fblink">
    <!-- nav foot right items FB #x2 -->
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ProgressionPhysiotherapyMassageFirstAid/" class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x pull-right"></a>
  </div>  

</div><!-- close nav fix bottom -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">+33 62738 5646</a></li>
    <li text-align="right"><a href="#">massage@progressionski.com</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="fblink">
    <!-- nav foot right items FB #x2 -->
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ProgressionPhysiotherapyMassageFirstAid/" target="_blank" class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x pull-right"></a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Nhan, it fixes the overlap in xs, but then creates a big gap between body content and nav-fixed-bottom when in larger screens. I think I may have to change it to nav-static-bottom

Comment: @Pietryszyn: I see, that's why a media query has been added. Just look at the code I've edited. The larger margin value works on small screens only. `@media (max-width: 479px)`